# Python chmod, Permission issue

Tags: python-3.x, chmod

I'm just having issues with the chmod method. I'm not exactly learned with programming but I've got some experience, and I'm trying to make a script to track the income and expenses of my small home business.

I think the issue is with the portion that writes to the file, or the chmod method, both near the bottom:

```
weeklyDatetime = datetime.now()
weeklyDate = weeklyDatetime.strftime("%Y, %m, %V - Incomes")

incomeFileNameAndDirectory = incomesPath + "\\" + weeklyDate + ".txt"
weeklyIncomeFile= open(incomeFileNameAndDirectory, "w+")
weeklyIncomeFile.close()

makingChoice = True
while makingChoice == True:
    print("1. Add another Income\n"
          "2. Stop adding incomes")
    
    addIncomeOrNo = input()

    if addIncomeOrNo == "1":
       print("Please enter the name of this income: ")
        incomeName = input()
        print("Please enter the amount of this income: ")
        incomeAmount = input()
        print("Please enter any additional descriptions for this income: ")
        incomeDescription = input()
        print("Thank you.\n")

        with open(incomesPath, "a") as weeklyIncomeFile:
            os.chmod(incomeFileNameAndDirectory, stat.S_IRWXO)
            weeklyIncomeFile.write("\n" + incomeName + "\t\t" + incomeAmount + "\t\t" + incomeDescription)
```

I think I'm maybe not using the os.chmod method correctly? I still get the following error:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\iarko\Desktop\PCE Business\Financials\Incomes'

Please let me know what the issue is, and thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in your line `with open(incomesPath, "a") as weeklyIncomeFile:`, in which you try to open a directory like a file.

In Python 3, I suggest to use:

- `pathlib` for the paths
- f-strings for printing values in strings

And also variables names are usually in lower case.

With these modifications taken into consideration, your code could look like that:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import check_output

weekly_datetime = datetime.now()
weekly_date = weekly_datetime.strftime("%Y, %m, %V - Incomes")

incomes_path = Path("C:\\Users\\iarko\\Desktop\\PCE Business\\Financials\\Incomes")

income_file_path = incomes_path / f"{weekly_date}.txt"
income_file_path.touch()
# If you need to set the correct access rights, use "icacls in Windows"
check_output(
    ["icacls", str(income_file_path), "/inheritance:r", "/grant:r", f"Everyone:F"]
)

making_choice = True
while making_choice == True:
    print("1. Add another Income\n2. Stop adding incomes")
    add_or_stop = input()

    if add_or_stop == "2":
        making_choice = False

    if add_or_stop == "1":
        print("Please enter the name of this income: ")
        name = input()
        print("Please enter the amount of this income: ")
        amount = input()
        print("Please enter any additional descriptions for this income: ")
        description = input()
        print("Thank you.\n")

        with open(income_file_path, "a") as f_income:
            f_income.write(f"\n{name}\t\t{amount}\t\t{description}")
```